# Additional params in Location Settings Result Callback

Tags: android, android-location

As per https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html
I've implemented the following snippet to check location settings of user.

```
public static checkLocSettings(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                           LocationRequest locationRequest,
                           final LocSettingInterface locSettingCallback) {

LocationSettingsRequest.Builder locationSettingsRequestVerifier = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .setAlwaysShow(true)
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

final PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, locationSettingsRequestVerifier.build());
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        final LocationSettingsStates=locationSettingsResult.getLocationSettingsStates();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                // initialize location requests here.
                locSettingCallback.onSuccess();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Now for each case, SUCCESS or RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, I need to fire my own interface. How can I pass the interface instant in `onResult()` of `ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>`

On a broader note, if I want to do anything inside SUCCESS or RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, I need to pass params to the callback. How can I do that?

I tried to access a final instance of interface inside onResult() but it is sometimes NULL, as expected.

UPDATE: Updated code snippet to show the `LocSettingInterface` that is getting NULL sometimes.

Comment: where you're creating the instance of your Interface? And can you update some sample code of your Interface.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. The instance is being created from another class, being passed as param into the method. The calling method in another class needs to know the result of location settings, that's why I need the interface.